# Using NestedScrollView how do I stop the body from scrolling under the headerSliverBuilder if the body still fits into the screen

Tags: flutter

I am creating a Sliver scroll but I noticed that even when the body is small enough to fit into the screen, the body still scrolls under the  `NestedScrollView header`. My Ideal experience is that the SliverAppBar Collapse but every item in the body stays underneath it and does not slide under.

[image: A sample of the situation I am facing]

Here is a code snippet of this:

```
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: const Text('HOME',),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          pinned: true,
          stretchTriggerOffset: 10,
          onStretchTrigger: () async{
            print('hello');
            return;
          },
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: const [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
              child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            )
          ],
          expandedHeight: 120,
          flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text('Charity',style:
            TextStyle(fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white),),
            stretchModes: [
              StretchMode.fadeTitle
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ];
    },
    body: SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverPadding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 11),
                sliver: SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(List.generate(
                    6,
                        (index) => Text('Tab One: $index'),
                  ),
                 ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

How can I make it such that if it is not small enough to fit into the page, it doesn't scroll under the header?

Comment: instead of `FlexibleSpaceBar `, you can use the `bottom` to fixed your second title.

Comment: @JahidulIslam doesn't solve the issue.